# Butterknife how to bindView from a different Views

Tags: android, view, butterknife

in my project I have this case:

```
@BindView(R.id.viewpager)
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;
AddParkingFragmentListener listener;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_parking, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, inflatedView);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return inflatedView;
}
```

where I need to bind a view that is in the `activity_main.xml` layout. 
I've thought that I could use an interface to disable the visibility directly in the MainActivity, but I would also know if there is the possibility to bind this view using Butterknife, because in the MainActivity I have also this problem:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    profile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPro); 

    //this views are in the navigation view, how to bind using butterknife?
    logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);

    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_profile);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

}
```

is there a way to do this or I need to use findViewById() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the oficial documentation from `Butter Knife Library`

They have included `findById` methods which simplify code that still has to find views on a `View`, `Activity`, or `Dialog`. It uses generics to infer the return type and automatically performs the cast.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.thing, null);
TextView firstName = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.first_name);
TextView lastName = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.last_name);
ImageView photo = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.photo);
```

Add a static import for `ButterKnife.findById` and enjoy even more fun.

Source: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: so I could use classic @BindView for normal views and ButterKnife.findById for others?

Comment: it is deprecated now

Comment: According to @Jake Wharton's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516835/5873832
we will use findViewById normally then