# ButterKnife findByID method is deprecated in version 8.8.0

Tags: android, butterknife

Hi I have just updated ButterKnife library version 8.7.0 to 8.8.0

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
```

and found that:

```
findById(view, id);
```

is deprecated, why? what method to use instead? 
but when reverting version to 8.7.0 (or earlier) deprecated warning disappears.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.some.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
...
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Per the [change log](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-880-2017-08-04):

> Deprecate the `findById` methods. Compile against API 26 and use the normal `findViewById` for the same functionality.

Android's`findViewById` has been updated to have the same functionality in API 26 which recently became stable, thus allowing Butter Knife's version to be deprecated and removed in the forthcoming v9.0.

Comment: Removing this method has incurred a lot of development time for the developers who just tried to update this library.