# Unable to use findById in ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I'm getting this error with ButterKnife:

> error: cannot find symbol method findById(View,int)

```
TextView tvHeaderTextOne = ButterKnife.findById(headerView, R.id.tv_header_text_one);
```

After updating to Butterknife 10 getting the error unable to `findById`.

Comment: looks like it's deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516835/8914336

Comment: I have been through that answer but still showing the error ?

Comment: Well perhaps they have removed it, I don't know. But when they say deprecated, it's better not to use it at all

Comment: yes not good to use I am working on a old project , below answer helped me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516753/butterknife-findbyid-method-is-deprecated-in-version-8-8-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define prop

```
@BindView( R.id.tv_header_text_one)
protected TextView tx ;
```

in OnCreate Method :

```
ButterKnife.bind(this,yourview);
```